# List only folders which matches the wildcard expression

Tags: wildcard, ls

Is there a command which lists all folders that matches a wildcard expression?  Example, if there are thousands of directories and I only want those ending in M or those starting in JO to be listed, can I do that with a certain Linux command? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` command, for example:

```
# find anything that start with 'jo' end with 'm' (case insensitive)
find . -iname 'jo*m'
```

You can execute any command after that, for example:

```
# find just like above but case sensitive, and move them to `/tmp`
find . -name 'JO*M' -exec mv -v {} /tmp \;
```

To find only a directory, you can use `-type d` flag, for example:

```
# find any directory that start with JO
find . -name 'JO*' -type d
```

Explanation, first argument is the starting directory, `.` means current directory. The next argument means the search criteria `-name` for case sensitive search, `-iname` for case insensitive search, `-type` for type of item search, `-exec` to execute certain command where the `{}` is the file name matched. You can learn more [here](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm) or for your specific case [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-a-directory-linux-command/).